# While mapping, how to access to Object keys inside loop? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array that contains all the keys that are supposed to be sent, the problem comes when I try to invoke them inside a for loop that is within a map, I get an error:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

If I print the array keys they will print well, but I can not point to them in a nested JSON array. Let me show what I mean

This is my array that contains all the keys

```
reportFieldsArr = [
0: "PrefixTitle"
1: "Company"
2: "Address"
3: "Zip"
]
```

I will pass that array to a function that will try to access every key in a `map`

When I try to do this is when I received the error, because can not access to `.reportFieldsArr[index]`:

```js
leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).reportFieldsArr[index]
```

Here it is the all function

```js
 filterLeads(leads,reportFieldsArr){ 
    this.leads = Array.from(new Set(leads.map(s => s.personId)))
    .map(id => {
      let leadFields:any = []
      for(let index = 0; index < reportFieldsArr.length; index++){
        leadFields[index] = leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).reportFieldsArr[index]
      }
      
      return leadFields
    });
  }
```

This is how is working right now, but it is with static data, I needed to be dynamic:

```js
filterLeads(leads,reportFieldsJSON,reportFieldsArr) { 
    this.leads = Array.from(new Set(leads.map(s => s.personId)))
    .map(id => {
      let leadFields:any =  {
        "PrefixTitle": leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).PrefixTitle,
        "Company": leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).Company,
        "Address": leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).Address,
        "Zip": leads.find(s => s.personId=== id).Zip,
      };
      
      return leadFields
   });
}
```

Comment: `reportFieldsArr` is not a valid array.

Comment: Why and how it could be a valid array? @AbhilashAugustine

Comment: An array should be made up of any valid object/ data type. In your example `0: "PrefixTitle"` is not valid object. It should be either `{0: "PrefixTitle}"` or `"PrefixTitle"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `reportFieldsArr = ["PrefixTitle", "Company", "Address", "Zip"]`, then you probably want to do

```
leadFields[index] = leads.find(s => s.personId=== id)[reportFieldsArr[index]];
```

(As @AbhilashAugustine noted in his comment, your `reportFieldsArr` is not syntactically correct).

Also, you don't have to repeat `leads.find()` with every iteration of the loop. Do something like this:

```
 filterLeads(leads,reportFieldsArr){ 
    this.leads = Array.from(new Set(leads.map(s => s.personId)))
    .map(id => {
      let leadFields:any = []
      const lead = leads.find(s => s.personId=== id);
      for(let index = 0; index < reportFieldsArr.length; index++){
        leadFields[index] = lead[reportFieldsArr[index]];
      }
      
      return leadFields;
    });
  }
```